# Calculating expected value for a gacha game

Tags: expected-value

I'm trying to do some sanity check on a gacha game I'm playing as I suspect their calculations are off. I've already done a monte-carlo simulation to verify my hypothesis, but I'm not sure how to do this statistically.

The rules of the game are as follows:

1. a player can do a "pull", which gives him a hero that is randomly selected
2. the more pulls a player does, the higher a chance of getting the hero that he wants
3. From pull 1 to 100, there's a 0.5% probability of success per pull (defined by getting the hero he wants)
4. From pull 101 to 199 there is a 1% probability of success per pull
5. If the player fails to get the hero he wants by turn 199, he will always get the hero on turn 200 (pity counter)
6. The probabilities and numbers of pull then reset to 0.5% and 0.

I can calculate the probability of a successful pull before turn 200 `1 - 0.995 ^ 100 * 0.99 ^ 99`, or around 78%. What I'm not too sure is how to calculate the average number of pulls required to get 1 copy (around 110-120 based on my simulations), as well as the average number of pulls required to get multiple (say 3) copies.

Is it possible to model this as some sort of equation, or do I need to use simulations?

Comment: Could you explain what it means to "get multiple copies"?  You have only described a process that appears to terminate once a "hero" is selected and how this translates to "multiple" and "copies" is unclear.

Comment: Ah, after you get a single hero, you can repeat the process again to get the same hero again as it's beneficial to get multiple copies of the same hero. So for instance, I could use 150 pulls to get one copy of the hero (0.5% probability for first 100 pulls and 50 pulls at 1%), and then when I try to get a second copy, my pulls reset at 0.5% probability again.